# Place an existing content type instance in an Orchard CMS content page

Tags: orchardcms

I'm learning Orchard CMS, and am trying to figure out how to place an existing content item.

I've created a new content type, and made it '**placeable**'.   Now when I'm editing a content page,  my new content type shows up in the right hand column under 'Content Items',  I can drag it into the layout which pops up a modal where I then create a new instance of the content type (which then gets inserted in the layout).

What I can't figure out, is how do I a place an existing (already created) instance of that content type into the layout?   This seems like something that should be easy to do but I can't find any mention of it on the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add existed content item to your layout, you can drag `Content Item` element (find it under `Content` group) from the right column:

[image]

Then, select the desired content item from this popup:

[image]

Here, you can select single or multiple items to be displayed with the display type.

Comment: Well that was embarrassingly easy.  Thanks, I'm really liking Orchard so far.